# Cut last character from string which was earlier splitted by char

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I want to order list with string names by name included in brackes.

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
            list.ForEach(elem => result.Add(elem.Value));
            result.Add(item);
            result = result.OrderBy(o=>o.Split(';')[0].Substring(0, o.Length - 1).Split('(')[1]).ToList();
```

**Example: 2-osobowy(Agrawka);Śniadanie+Obiadokolacja**
I want to extract this name **Agrawka**
How to change instruction `Substring(0, o.Length - 1)`to cut last char from splitted string in orderby instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right understood you want extract values in the brackets and sort input' list by that values. So code below sorts your data and extracts value to additional list:

```
        List<string> resultList = new List<string>() { "2-osobowy(Bgrawka);Śniadanie+Obiadokolacja", "2-osobowy(Agrawka);Śniadanie+Obiadokolacja" };
        string tempStr = null;
        var extractedStr = new List<String>();
        resultList = resultList.OrderBy(o =>
        {
            var extract = (tempStr = o.Split(';')[0].Split('(')[1]).Substring(0, tempStr.Length - 1);
            extractedStr.Add(extract);
            return extract;
        }).ToList();
```

If you want only sort input data just simplify the lambda:

```
        resultList = resultList.OrderBy(o => (tempStr = o.Split(';')[0].Split('(')[1]).Substring(0, tempStr.Length - 1)).ToList();
```